# Socket Exception when trying to debug in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have service in `C#` and it consumes a nuget package/library into which I want to debug to. 
Now, it makes sense to **disable** the "**Enable my Code**" option in Visual studio debugger to debug the library code.

[image]

However, every time I do this and run the application, I get an error as attached. 
When I enable the "Enable my code" it works fine.

But that stops me debugging into my code.

Has anyone faced this issue earlier?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Socket Exception when trying to debug in Visual Studio 2017

You can try to check "Thrown" for `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` with the following steps:

Click Debug menu -> Windows->Execption setings-> Expand "`Common Language Runtime Exceptions`" until you reach "`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`" -> Check this exception, please refer to the following screenshot:

[image]

Certificate: [Sockets.cs not found](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9af6de3c-542d-42eb-a33b-bf4c1db0c04d/socketscs-not-found?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Hope this helps.